# Power off vm when UPS kicks in

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

I am currently implementing a UPS (APC BR1200) for servers and NAS in a school. We have one physical servers running multiple instances of VM using VMWare workstation.

The APC UPS is connected to the physical server via a USB. I would like to know how could I get the VM to power off first followed by the physical server when the UPS kicks in during an outage.

I managed to power off the VM using vmrun command.  Could I used apcupsd to run a batch file or command once it detect the UPS kicks in? If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works with VMWare, but with Hyper-V if the physical host shuts down the VMs will be shut down gracefully first. So all you'd have to do is configure the UPS to shut down the host and the VMs would get shut down automatically first.

Comment: The first obvious thing is, why are you trying to use VMware Workstation in this context?

Comment: @Twisty, thank you. I will give it a try first and see what is the results.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, it was already configured when I first join in by the previous IT guys. So, I had no idea why they went that route.